# Cannot get JApplet to work. Everytime I run the program I get an error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, japplet

Every time I run my code I get this error listed at the top of the code.

I had the program without the color changing working fine, but ever since I added in the ability to change the color of the number I cannot get it to work for the life of me. Any help is appreciated. This program is a problem for my Java Class.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ColorChange.init(ColorChange.java:29)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ColorChange extends JApplet implements ItemListener, 
ActionListener
{


private JRadioButton blackRb, blueRb, orangeRb, greenRb, yellowRb, redRb, 
pinkRb, grayRb;
private Color currentColor=Color.magenta;   
private ButtonGroup colorSelect;    
private JTextField numberTF;
private JLabel label;
private JButton okB;
private int num=0;

public void init() {

Container c=getContentPane();
c.setLayout(null);
setSize(500,300);

label=new JLabel("Enter number");
label.setLocation(200,40);
label.setSize(100,30);

numberTF=new JTextField(1);
numberTF.setLocation(300,40);

okB.setLocation(400,40);
okB.setSize(50,30);
okB.addActionListener(this);

c.add(label);
c.add(numberTF);
c.add(okB);

blackRb=new JRadioButton("Black");
blueRb=new JRadioButton("Blue");
orangeRb=new JRadioButton("Orange");
greenRb=new JRadioButton("Green");
yellowRb=new JRadioButton("Yellow");
redRb=new JRadioButton("Red");
pinkRb=new JRadioButton("Pink");
grayRb=new JRadioButton("Grey");

blackRb.setSize(100,30);
blueRb.setSize(100,30);
orangeRb.setSize(100,30);
greenRb.setSize(100,30);
yellowRb.setSize(100,30);
redRb.setSize(100,30);
pinkRb.setSize(100,30);
grayRb.setSize(100,30);

blackRb.setLocation(200,70);
blueRb.setLocation(200,100);
orangeRb.setLocation(200,130);
greenRb.setLocation(200,160);
yellowRb.setLocation(400,70);
redRb.setLocation(400,100);
pinkRb.setLocation(400,130);
grayRb.setLocation(400,160);

blackRb.addActionListener(this);
blueRb.addActionListener(this);
orangeRb.addActionListener(this);
greenRb.addActionListener(this);
yellowRb.addActionListener(this);
redRb.addActionListener(this);
pinkRb.addActionListener(this);
grayRb.addActionListener(this);

c.add(blackRb);
c.add(blueRb);
c.add(orangeRb);
c.add(greenRb);
c.add(yellowRb);
c.add(redRb);
c.add(pinkRb);
c.add(grayRb);

colorSelect=new ButtonGroup();

colorSelect.add(blackRb);
colorSelect.add(blueRb);
colorSelect.add(orangeRb);
colorSelect.add(greenRb);
colorSelect.add(yellowRb);
colorSelect.add(redRb);
colorSelect.add(pinkRb);
colorSelect.add(grayRb);

}


public void paint(Graphics g)
{
super.paint(g);
g.setColor(currentColor);
switch (num)
{

case 0:
    g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,50,25,175);
    g.fillRect(50,200,125,25);
    g.fillRect(150,25,25,175);
    break;

case 1:
    g.fillRect(75,25,75,25);
    g.fillRect(100,50,50,125);
    g.fillRect(50,175,150,25);
    break;

case 2:
    g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
    g.fillRect(150,50,25,50);
    g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,125,25,50);
    break;

case 3:
    g.fillRect(150,50,25,175);
    g.fillRect(50,50,100,25);
    g.fillRect(50,125,100,25);
    g.fillRect(50,200,100,25);
    break;

case 4:
    g.fillRect(50,25,25,75);
    g.fillRect(50,100,100,25);
    g.fillRect(150,25,25,175);
    break;

case 5:
    g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,50,25,50);
    g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
    g.fillRect(150,125,25,50);
    break;

case 6:
    g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,50,25,50);
    g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
    g.fillRect(150,125,25,50);
    g.fillRect(50,125,25,50);
    break;

case 7:
    g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
    g.fillRect(150,50,25,150);
    break;

case 8:
    g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,50,25,50);
    g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
    g.fillRect(150,125,25,50);
    g.fillRect(50,125,25,50);
    g.fillRect(150,50,25,50);
    break;

case 9:
default:
    g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,50,25,50);
    g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
    g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
    g.fillRect(150,125,25,50);
    g.fillRect(150,50,25,50);
    break;
 }
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
{
if(e.getSource()==blackRb)
    currentColor=Color.black;
else if(e.getSource()==blueRb)
    currentColor=Color.blue;
else if(e.getSource()==orangeRb)
    currentColor=Color.orange;
else if(e.getSource()==greenRb)
    currentColor=Color.green;
else if(e.getSource()==yellowRb)
    currentColor=Color.yellow;
else if(e.getSource()==redRb)
    currentColor=Color.red;
else if(e.getSource()==pinkRb)
    currentColor=Color.pink;
else if(e.getSource()==grayRb)
    currentColor=Color.gray;
repaint();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Ok"))
            num=Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());
    repaint();

}

}
```

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  ..

Comment: .. As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: BTW - line 29 of the code seems to be `label.setSize(100,30);` which does not seem logical for a `NullPointerException` given that `label.setLocation(200,40);` on the previous line worked. Are you sure that *exact* code shown, produced this error? It didn't leave out a `package` statement for example?

Answer (score 1):

your okB jbutton variable is never initialized.

Comment: BTW - the button is not large enough to display 'OK' here. Just 'O'. Another reason for using layouts rather than guessing what size components need to be. The layout of the color choices is well suited to a `GridLayout` but having said that, look into `JColorChooser` - a 'working version' of what this code seems to be attempting.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your modified working code and find out what you missed.

```
//<applet width="500" height="300" code="ColorChange"></applet>

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ColorChange extends JApplet implements ItemListener, ActionListener {

    private JRadioButton blackRb, blueRb, orangeRb, greenRb, yellowRb, redRb, pinkRb, grayRb;
    private Color currentColor=Color.magenta;   
    private ButtonGroup colorSelect;    
    private JTextField numberTF;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton okB;
    private int num=0;

    public void init() {

        Container c=getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
        setSize(500,300);

        label=new JLabel("Enter number");
        label.setLocation(200,40);
        label.setSize(100,30);

        numberTF=new JTextField(5);
        numberTF.setLocation(300,40);
        numberTF.setSize(50,30);

        okB = new JButton("Ok");
        okB.setLocation(400,40);
        okB.setSize(80,30);
        okB.addActionListener(this);

        c.add(label);
        c.add(numberTF);
        c.add(okB);

        blackRb=new JRadioButton("Black");
        blueRb=new JRadioButton("Blue");
        orangeRb=new JRadioButton("Orange");
        greenRb=new JRadioButton("Green");
        yellowRb=new JRadioButton("Yellow");
        redRb=new JRadioButton("Red");
        pinkRb=new JRadioButton("Pink");
        grayRb=new JRadioButton("Grey");

        blackRb.setSize(100,30);
        blueRb.setSize(100,30);
        orangeRb.setSize(100,30);
        greenRb.setSize(100,30);
        yellowRb.setSize(100,30);
        redRb.setSize(100,30);
        pinkRb.setSize(100,30);
        grayRb.setSize(100,30);

        blackRb.setLocation(200,70);
        blueRb.setLocation(200,100);
        orangeRb.setLocation(200,130);
        greenRb.setLocation(200,160);
        yellowRb.setLocation(400,70);
        redRb.setLocation(400,100);
        pinkRb.setLocation(400,130);
        grayRb.setLocation(400,160);

        blackRb.addItemListener(this);
        blueRb.addItemListener(this);
        orangeRb.addItemListener(this);
        greenRb.addItemListener(this);
        yellowRb.addItemListener(this);
        redRb.addItemListener(this);
        pinkRb.addItemListener(this);
        grayRb.addItemListener(this);

        c.add(blackRb);
        c.add(blueRb);
        c.add(orangeRb);
        c.add(greenRb);
        c.add(yellowRb);
        c.add(redRb);
        c.add(pinkRb);
        c.add(grayRb);

        colorSelect=new ButtonGroup();

        colorSelect.add(blackRb);
        colorSelect.add(blueRb);
        colorSelect.add(orangeRb);
        colorSelect.add(greenRb);
        colorSelect.add(yellowRb);
        colorSelect.add(redRb);
        colorSelect.add(pinkRb);
        colorSelect.add(grayRb);

    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(currentColor);

        switch (num) {
            case 0:
                g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,50,25,175);
                g.fillRect(50,200,125,25);
                g.fillRect(150,25,25,175);
                break;

            case 1:
                g.fillRect(75,25,75,25);
                g.fillRect(100,50,50,125);
                g.fillRect(50,175,150,25);
                break;

            case 2:
                g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
                g.fillRect(150,50,25,50);
                g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,125,25,50);
                break;

            case 3:
                g.fillRect(150,50,25,175);
                g.fillRect(50,50,100,25);
                g.fillRect(50,125,100,25);
                g.fillRect(50,200,100,25);
                break;

            case 4:
                g.fillRect(50,25,25,75);
                g.fillRect(50,100,100,25);
                g.fillRect(150,25,25,175);
                break;

            case 5:
                g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,50,25,50);
                g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
                g.fillRect(150,125,25,50);
                break;

            case 6:
                g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,50,25,50);
                g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
                g.fillRect(150,125,25,50);
                g.fillRect(50,125,25,50);
                break;

            case 7:
                g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
                g.fillRect(150,50,25,150);
                break;

            case 8:
                g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,50,25,50);
                g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
                g.fillRect(150,125,25,50);
                g.fillRect(50,125,25,50);
                g.fillRect(150,50,25,50);
                break;

            case 9:
                default:
                g.fillRect(50,25,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,50,25,50);
                g.fillRect(50,100,125,25);
                g.fillRect(50,175,125,25);
                g.fillRect(150,125,25,50);
                g.fillRect(150,50,25,50);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {        
        if(e.getSource()==blackRb)
            currentColor=Color.black;
        else if(e.getSource()==blueRb)
            currentColor=Color.blue;
        else if(e.getSource()==orangeRb)
            currentColor=Color.orange;
        else if(e.getSource()==greenRb)
            currentColor=Color.green;
        else if(e.getSource()==yellowRb)
            currentColor=Color.yellow;
        else if(e.getSource()==redRb)
            currentColor=Color.red;
        else if(e.getSource()==pinkRb)
            currentColor=Color.pink;
        else if(e.getSource()==grayRb)
            currentColor=Color.gray;
        repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Ok"))
            num=Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());
        repaint();
    }
}
```